# Is it possible to inject variables inside a TestNG dataprovider class

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a Test class and a separate data provider class as below. My test class extends `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`, so i am able to inject variables in my test class. But when I tried injecting the variable inside the data provider class, it is not working. (I even tried extending it with   `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`). While debugging, I could see that the autowiring is happening only while instantiating the test class.

```
@Test(dataProviderClass = MyDataProvider.class)
public class MyTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{

    @Inject
    XYZ x; //works
    
    @Test(dataProvider = "dataSet1")
    public void testMethod1(){
        //
    }
}
```

```
public class MyDataProvider {

    @Inject
    XYZ x;// not working
    
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] dataSet1(){
        //
    }
}
```

Then I tried to do it by setting the attribute to `ITestContext`

```
@Test(dataProviderClass = MyDataProvider.class)
public class MyTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{

    @Inject
    XYZ x; 


    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass(ITestContext context){
        context.setAttribute("x",x);
    }
    
    @Test(dataProvider = "dataSet1")
    public void testMethod1(){
        //
    }
}
```

```
public class MyDataProvider {
   
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] dataSet1(ITestContext context){
        XYZ x = (XYZ) context.getAttribute("x");
    }
}
```

Even though the above method works, it looks like a work around and also I need to add the `ITestContext` parameter to every data provider method.

So, I would like to know

1. Whether injection is possible inside the data provider class.
2. Is there are any better way to do this? (Similar to before class method, are there any before method available for data provider so that I need not pass `ITestContext` to every data provider method)